# How is the #_user_profiles table used

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am trying to figure out how this table is used. More importantly I want to write to it in a simple way without having to build a special form or write to the db directly. Currently I have a site with a plugin called miniorange that manages sso logins and writes three user attributes to this table when a user first logs in. I can created users manually but am not able to populate the three attributes (First Name, Last Name, Staff ID) that are held in this table. Is there some existing joomla mechanism such as the user creation interface that can be used to write to this table or you have to build something that will write directly to this table?

I  using joomla  3.9.16.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] when you have a moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no code for managing data in this table. You have to write your own plugin for this. You can take a look at `User - Profile` plugin for example.

Comment: see also https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin